# Spark saveAsTextFile going slow

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, pyspark

In pyspark I read in a very big directory, around 4 TB, and after mapping it, it looks like it will take days to save back in. I can't really wait, but my pipe breaks anyway and I'm forced out of Spark, so thats not really an option.

I'm looking for a faster away, whether it is saving the files as Gzip, or passing some parameters to my cluster, or anything, to accelerate the save action.

note: I coalesce at 22500 to give me 22500 files at around 500 MB (I think) - but I don't know if the number of partitions are whats important.

```
datum = sc.textFile("s3n://file/path/*")

data2json = datum.map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
dataNew = data2json.flatMap(Encodes)
identifier = str(uuid.uuid4())
fileNamed = 's3n://new-file/path/new-files/' + identifier
dataNew.coalesce(225000, 'true').saveAsTextFile(fileNamed)
```

Encodes is a user defined function below. It splits a JSON record into multiple JSON records.

```
def schemaEncode(jsStr):
    json_objects = []
    jst = json.loads(jsStr[0])
    entry = jsStr[0]
    val_one = jst['_id']
    id = val_one[val_one.keys()[0]]
    jst.pop('_id')
    attribute_names = []
    attribute_type = []
    attribute_value = []
    elements = jst.keys()
    for k in elements:
        attribute_names.append(k) #attribute names
        attribute_type.append(jst[k].keys()[0]) #add type (s, i , sS)
        attribute_value.append(jst[k][jst[k].keys()[0]]) #add value
    for i in range(len(attribute_names)):
        json_objects.append(json.dumps({'id':id, 'attr_type':attribute_type[i], 'attr_name':attribute_names[i], 'attr_value':attribute_value[i]}))
    return json_objects
```

I have 18 Slaves running on AWS EC2. The log outputs look like this:

```
15/12/09 20:39:46 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 1711.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1718, 172.33.33.30, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2482 bytes)
15/12/09 20:39:46 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 1675.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1681) in 55111 ms on 172.33.33.30 (1676/45856)
15/12/09 20:39:46 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 1712.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1719, 172.33.33.113, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2482 bytes)
15/12/09 20:39:46 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 1679.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1685) in 51953 ms on 172.33.33.113 (1677/45856)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataNew.coalesce(225000, false)
```

Coalesce but disable the shuffle, shuffle is very expensive and will occupy lots of I/O and network.

Comment: OK Thanks. Right now I have 45k~ tasks. Would it be wiser to increase the number to 225k like above, or decrease it, if I care about speed?